# WPF How to add rows to a DataGrid at runtime then add text to these rows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with three columns (step number, requirement number, description). Once the application is run the user shall choose an excel spreadsheet and I am pulling information from this spreadsheet to fill into my `DataGrid`. In my code I already have the strings I need i just need to know how to programmatically add a row then fill said row with these strings.

Heres my `DataGrid`:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,167,11,10" 
 SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" MinColumnWidth="22">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Step Number" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Requirement" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is the loop I want to be creating rows in:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> Req in reqLocations)
  {
    //create row

    // ADD INFO FROM DICTIONARY INTO A ROW
  }
```

Comment: Set dataGrid.ItemsSource to ObservableCollection<T> and then Add to the ObservableCollection it should automatically add rows in datagrid

Comment: Have you researched MVVM for WPF yet? As your problem is exactly what it is meant for. Do not try to programatically create Datagrid Rows as that can be fully automated for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After agreeing with  comments, if you still want to look into.... below is simple example for your XAML

Create a simple class with all your data column headers

```
 public class dataGriditems
 {
    public string StepNumber { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }             

 }
```

In the XAML add the binding for each column and ensure the binding name is same as the class properties, that you are going add as item source (In this case the above class)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Step Number" Binding="{Binding StepNumber}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Requirement" Binding="{Binding Requirement}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" />
```

In the XAML set AutoGenerateColumns="False" for data grid.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,167,11,10" 
 SelectionChanged="dataGrid_SelectionChanged" MinColumnWidth="22" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

In the code, create a simple list of objects of above defined class and assign the list to `dataGrid.ItemsSource` as shown below

```
List<dataGriditems> items = new List<dataGriditems>();

 items.Add(new dataGriditems() { StepNumber = "one", Requirement = "req1", Description = "desc1"});
 items.Add(new dataGriditems() { StepNumber = "two", Requirement = "req2", Description = "desc2" });
 items.Add(new dataGriditems() { StepNumber = "three", Requirement = "req3", Description = "desc3" });
 items.Add(new dataGriditems() { StepNumber = "four", Requirement = "req4", Description = "desc4" });

 dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help on this issue. I ended up using this solution but now Ive run into another road block maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063765/wpf-how-to-i-edit-rows-in-a-datagrid-that-i-added-programmatically-c-sharp