# WPF how to I edit rows in a DataGrid that I added programmatically C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my application I have an empty `DataGrid` with three columns created in xaml:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Step Number" Binding="{Binding StepNumber}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Requirement" Binding="{Binding Requirement}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I am using the following code to add items (Rows) to the `DataGrid`:

```
 Dictionary<string, List<int>> reqLocations = modifier.ValidateRequirements(col, startRow, RequirementCallbackHandler, CredentialHandler);

  List<DataGridItems> rowItems = new List<DataGridItems>();

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> kvp in reqLocations)
  {
    // Create Rows
    rowItems.Add(new DataGridItems() { StepNumber = ReturnStepNumber(kvp.Value[0]), Requirement = kvp.Key, Description = "Loading Requirement..." });
  }

  // Add Items source to DataGrid
  dataGrid.ItemsSource = rowItems ;
```

During runtime I need to edit these rows to fill in the description column. how can I achieve this? thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

To be clear I need to edit these rows through code not manually.

For the person that asked me to include more code, its just a small class here is the code:

```
public class DataGridItems
{
  public string StepNumber { get; set; }
  public string Requirement { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public ValidityState state { get; set; }
  public HUDI.IJMPSRequirement req { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: It's been a while that i've worked with wpf but if i'm right you just have to set your data grid control to be editable. Please try it

Comment: You can also have a look at the CellEditEnding event. The DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs provides access to the EditingElement e.g. a TextBox. Then you "simply" have to find your row in your collection (maybe you use unique id's) and set the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...  First off you are binding to...  something, but then immediately replacing that binding with a new source (your rowItems list).  If you don't care to try and make your application MVVM, just throw away you data columns definition in the xaml (the grid will pick those up from your rowItems list) and then when you edit your description field in the data grid the rowItems in your code behind will be updated.  From there what you do with that list is up to you in terms of persistence or what have you.

If you want to stay in MVVM land then keep the bindings and get rid of the code behind and instead set the datacontext of your data grid to the ViewModel that is holding the things you are binding to.

Maybe add some more code (what does your DataGridItems class look like? What does the ViewModel you are binding to look like?) or some more context?

Answer (score 0):

Set below property of Datagrid and once done set it to True

`datagrid.IsReadOnly = False;`